# ¿Como cambio la configuración por defecto del Tab Size de SublimeText 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

Al crear cualquier archivo en SublimeText 3 el IDE tiene por defecto un tab size de 4 y tengo que ir siempre a la opción inferior derecha del entorno de trabajo para modificarla, ¿como y en donde podría modificar esto para que en cuanto cree un archivo me aparezca la tabulación que deseo?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Estaran esos archivos como solo lectura? tenes permisos sobre ellos?

Answer (score 0):

Para modificar tab size se realiza en las configuraciones de usuario  y lo haces desde el menú superior en "Preferences" y de ahí nos dirigimos a "Settings", se abrirán dos pestañas, la del lado izquierdo son las configuraciones por default y la del lado derecho es la que se modificara de la siguiente manera:

{
    "tab_size": 2,
    "font_size": 13
}

y listo dejamos de manera preestablecida que la tabulación en 2 y el tamaño de la fuente en 13( pude que ya se tengan algunas lineas de código en este archivo, solo hay que agregar lo que requerimos y listo)